# WebDriver - how to pass object locator as parameter in data driven test?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, data-driven

I'm wondering if it's possible to pass locator as parameter in data driven test? For example:

```
    //this is non-parameterized object RADIO_BUTTON locator

    WebElement radiobElm = driver.findElement(RADIO_BUTTON);
    radiobElm.click();

    vs. 

    //I'd like to pass locator "RADIO_BUTTON" as string (strRadioButton) from Excel sheet, so for each test iteration my script will click on different radio-buttons. Is it possible? 

    WebElement radiobElm = driver.findElement(strRadioButton);
    radioElm.click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the many ways to accomplish this would be to use same method to find elements and read the locator from excel file.

```
 WebElement radiobElm = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Your xpath string from exel"));
```

Of course you have to do all of other works to read the correct cell from excel.

Comment: I am glad that it worked! Please accept this as an answer and THAT is the way to thanks the people answer your question in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You just have to get the data from the excel (using jexcelapi's [getContents()](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Cell.html#getContents()) method, for instance). Then, you can manipulate them accordingly as they come.

**1-** If it's an **xpath**, use this:

```
WebElement radiobElm = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Cell contents containing xpath of the webelement"));
radioElm.click();
```

**2-** If it's an **id**, use this:

```
WebElement radiobElm = driver.findElement(By.id("Cell contents containing id of the webelement"));
radioElm.click();
```

**3-** If it's an **cssSelector**, use this:

```
WebElement radiobElm = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("Cell contents containing cssSelector of the webelement"));
radioElm.click();
```

Similar thing, can be applied for **"className, name, linkText, partialLinkText, and tagName"** also.